# What does "IVA Discriminado" mean on car websites in Portugal?

Tags: significado, termos

What does "**IVA Discriminado**" mean on the car websites in Portugal?

I have tried to look for information on Google but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Fyi, to look in Portugal from the states or another country, you have to use: site:.pt Just googling won't work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IVA in English is VAT, **value-added tax** which is used in the EU and not in, for example, the States.

discriminar here means to *state the amount* of the VAT tax.

> Obrigações do locador O locador (empresa que aluga o carro) é
> responsável por incluir o valor do IVA no preço do aluguel e emitir
> uma fatura com o valor discriminado. Além disso, ele é obrigado a
> recolher o imposto e repassá-lo ao Estado.

[From a car rental company in Portugal: Total Renting](https://totalrenting.pt/blog/glossario/iva-carro/)

Translation: Obligations of the lessor (the rental company): The rental company is responsible for including the VAT amount in the rental price and issuing an invoice with that amount listed. Also, the company is obligated to collect the tax and onpass it to the state [government in US lingo].

So, the rental company collects it from the customer then pays it to the state.

IVA discriminado: stated VAT amount

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Does it mean that one of them (buyer or seller) needs **to add** VAT?

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent It is very clear in my translation of the Portuguese text. The company **includes the VAT (tax) on its bill** to the client, the client pays the bill to the company and the company passes on that amount to the government. Yes, the company is the one who puts the VAT amount on the bill. My answer states: the company includes the VAT amount in the price.

Comment: I think I would expect it to say VAT included in the UK but prices to the consumer are almost always inclusive of VAT and so it is never mentioned. Business to business sites do quote net of VAT.

Comment: @mdewey I can only give you what I found and not a general statement about who does or does not show VAT. I know when I was a freelancer in France, some companies asked me to show it, others not. Some paid the VAT for me, others did not.

Answer (score 1):

IVA is a tax. [Please refer to the Portuguese Official Website of Public Services](https://eportugal.gov.pt/cidadaos-europeus-viajar-viver-e-fazer-negocios-em-portugal/impostos-para-atividades-economicas-em-portugal/imposto-sobre-valor-acrescentado-iva-em-portugal) for more details.

**Discriminar** in "*IVA discriminado em fatura*" means "to describe", "to make evident". I've googled about it and it seems like there's a rule in Portugal about vehicles with IVA registered in the invoice being eligible for auto financing.